# Inconsistent results from AC_CHECK_FUNCS

Tags: autotools, autoconf, configure

I am having a problem with a configure script verifying the presence of some basic functions,

```
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([floor gettimeofday memset pow sqrt sin exp])
```

Under certain criteria, the results are expected (`checking for x... yes`). Otherwise the math functions above are claimed to be not defined. The difference is a call to verify some lapack routines first. These are checked by, `AC_CHECK_LIB([lapack],[dsyev_],...`. If these checks are not done first, then the above math functions fail to check (final compilation works).

I've reduced the configure script to the following that recreates the issue,

```
AC_INIT([TEST], [0.0], [none@none.com])
#AC_CHECK_LIB([lapack],[dsyev_], , AC_MSG_FAILURE([Missing lapack]))
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([floor gettimeofday memset pow sqrt sin exp])
```

Uncommenting the second line results in proper visual results. I imagine that the math library isn't included or checked for some reason. In fact, `AC_CHECK_LIB([m],[exp])` works fine.

What's the cause of this, and what is the proper way to use this directive? What kind of x-platform considerations should I observe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The math functions are in the math library, so if you want them, you need to pull the math library into the link arguments that `configure` uses.  `AC_CHECK_LIB([m],[exp])` is one way to do that. The reason that `AC_CHECK_LIB([lapack],...)` also has that effect is that it quite probably pulls in `-lm` itself (not knowing the library, but I read it's for linear algebra).

I suggest that you avoid `AC_CHECK_LIB` and instead use `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` for functions that are potentially not in the standard C library.  So

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(exp, m)
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(dsyev_, lapack)
```

(But using `AC_CHECK_LIB` is not actually wrong.)

Comment: Do you have any more insight on why searching for `lapack` produces correct results for `ac_check_funcs` later? It must modify the environment, but what?

Comment: Why use AC_SEARCH_LIBS? Is there a systemic advantage? A 'suggestion' only goes so far when I'm sitting in front of a 1k lines of a configure file. Ugh, when I finally overhaul this configure script, buy stock in Scotch companies.

Comment: `configure` adds any library it finds to the `LIBS` variable and uses that for subsequent tests.  `lapack` is probably linked with `libm`, so linking against `lapack` makes the symbols in `libm` available.

Comment: With `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` you tend to only pull in the libraries that you actually need.  For example, on some platforms a certain function might be in `libc` rather than `libm`, but there still might be a `libm` anyway that you don't need.  The difference in practice might be small, but I think it's cleaner.

Comment: Yeah, I had figured it was something like that. I was just about to write back that my LIBS variable is set to that by default, but it is not. I will have to look into the cross-platform implications into it --if any. Thanks.

Comment: It's probably aesthetically better to do both.  That is, invoke AC_CHECK_LIB or AC_SEARCH_LIBS (for the math library, AC_CHECK_LIB is fine as you don't really have to check any name other than "m") first to get -lm in LIBS, and then invoke AC_CHECK_FUNCS to verify that all the functions you need are present.  This is probably overkill for libm (does any implementation of libm include sin but not include cos?  Not if it's standard) but may be appropriate for less stable libraries.